# Java code's CPU usage changing

Tags: java

I ran into this observation when I was trying to give a rough estimate of my code's runtime: The CPU usage stayed at around 10% for the first part of the code, which involved traversing 2 strings and tossing things into a hashset. When the code reached the second part (2 nested for loops, plus a gigantic array allocation), the CPU usage skyrocketed to 50%.

I don't think I did anything related to multithreading. Also if I slightly modify the first part (something really simple like adding another for loop), the CPU usage varies a lot too. Why is this happening? A bit curious about who's utilizing the CPU consumption.

Comment: 10% per CPU or 10% across a set of CPUs.  What does top/task manager say is consuming the CPU?

Comment: @CharlesForsythe Java(TM) Platform SE binary is I'm talking about

Comment: That's not what I asked.  When the JVM is using 10% of the CPU, is that 10% of a single CPU, or 10% of all of the CPUs available?  What other processes are using the rest of the CPU capacity?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily a direct comparison between your code being ran and the CPU usage as the JVM will fluctuate CPU usage based on what is in the heap at that point in time while it manages garbage collection.  If it suddenly went up to 50% then back down this may be coincidence as at the same time garbage collection kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more detailed information by running jvisualvm.exe, which is located in your jdk bin folder.  I'm not sure how much CPU usage info is available out of the box, but there are at least plugins that will give you CPU usage info.  This is also a graphical way to see heap usage, as per david99world's answer.

http://visualvm.java.net/index.html